# Azure Search .Net SDK: Dictionary to fields

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-search

My application allows Azure Cognitive Search text fields to be added after runtime.

Is there any way to populating these fields using the [.Net ACS SKD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Search.Documents/)?

E.g.

```
public class DynamicDocument {
  [SimpleField(IsKey = true)]
  public string id {get; set;}
  
  // How to unnest these?
  public Dictionary<string,string> attributes {get; set;}
}
```

...or is the only option to skip the SDK and make the HTTP calls directly (potentially using something like JsonExtensionData to serialise the dictionary)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use [SearchDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.models.searchdocument?view=azure-dotnet) to both read and write generic results from ACS.  Therefore it's just a matter of mapping your POCOs to instances of SearchDocument.